# Can't load Java applet from another directory in HTML

Tags: java, html, applet, directory

When i try to load an applet with :

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
  <param name="code" value="Sokoban" />
</object>
```

when the html file is in the same directory as the applet it loads as expected.

But when the applet is in an another directory the following code won't work :

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
  <param name="code" value="sokoban/Sokoban" />
</object>
```

(sokoban is the directory the applet is in, Sokoban is the applet => Sokoban.class)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `deployJava.js` to deploy the applet (linked from the [applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info)).
2. Use the `codebase` attribute to point to the `sokoban` directory.
3. Since the `code` attribute needs to be the fully qualified class name, return it to just `Sokoban`